# Junit @BeforeClass and @AfterClass behavior in case of multiple test cases

Tags: java, junit

Folks,

Say I have a complicated sub-classed test suite that I run regularly. As a part of this, I am trying to ensure that each test class is executed strictly one after the other, and that `Test2`'s `@BeforeClass` method will NOT start before `Test1`'s `@AfterClass` is done. Is this a valid assumption to make?

An Example Scenario:

Class `TestBase` has an `@BeforeClass` and an `@AfterClass` method.

Class `T1` derives from `TestBase`.

Class `T2` derives from `TestBase.

We run `T1` and `T2` together from Ant / Eclipse. There are some common static objects from TestBase reused between `T1` and `T2`, meaning I have to be totally sure that these are destroyed completely in `AfterClass` before the next round of `BeforeClass` start to initialize the same. Can I be sure of this with the basic usage outlined above?

I have a strong suspicion that this is not happening, but simplistic tests are not proving the same. Documentation doesn't talk about this either. So I want to ensure that I am not trying to solve a systemic issue that can be solved otherwise.

Comment: See this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1924371/699224) - can you generate some similar println() output to demonstrate the ordering of your `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` calls?

Comment: I tried that with a simplistic test case, And am not able to repro the behavior. I don't want to take that as gospel though - I wanted to understand Junit's implementation promises to be sure. My actual tests with messages are still running.

Answer (score 2):

Excluding parallel execution, JUnit should always run one test class after, i.e T1 before T2 (or the other way around), so your scenario should work.

The other thing to be aware of is the order in which the tests are run, which may confuse the issue. See my answer to [Has JUnit4 begun supporting ordering of test? Is it intentional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845929/has-junit4-begun-supporting-ordering-of-test-is-it-intentional/7846712#7846712), which explains why the tests may be executed in different orders.

I think your best solution would be to use a [ClassRule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/ClassRule.html). This allows you to define a class which implements your `AfterClass` & `BeforeClass` behaviour. For instance:

```
public class UsesExternalResource {
  public static Server myServer= new Server();

  @ClassRule
  public static ExternalResource resource= new ExternalResource() {
    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
      myServer.connect();
    };

    @Override
    protected void after() {
      myServer.disconnect();
    };
  };
}
```

Using this may remove the need to have static variables, because you can do all of your setup in the `ClassRule`, everything could be an instance variable in there. You may be able to remove the `TestBase` parent class altogether.

Comment: I actually don't care about the order as long as they are executed. I care mainly about testcases being serialized - thanks for the answer though!