# JUnit4 Run A method After Some Methods?

Tags: java, junit4

I have a method that is not a regular test method. It is a cleanup method. I want to run it after some methods (some methods that are not test methods but are called from some test methods ).

How can do that using JUnit4?

PS: After and AfterClass are not a choice. I want to run a method after "some" non test methods (some methods that are called within test methods).

Comment: You can run a method `@Before` test method. :)

Comment: @AleksandrM You probably mean `@After` :)

Comment: @Bart: `@After` was too obvious.

Comment: And wouldn't work, because the OP wants it run after *arbitrary* methods, not *all*, and not tests.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Could probably write some logic inside `@After` method to check for *some arbitrary* method and this methods *are called from some test methods*.

Comment: Personally, I'm skeptical of the test's structure and/or test suite organization, if this is a legitimate current need.

Comment: And that doesn't feels like good **unit** testing.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried @`AfterClass` And @`After` ,`@Before` ,`@BeforeClass` ?

for the case of @`AfterClass` your method should be static .
in these case your method would be launched once before all the Tests.

check this link.
[junit-beforeclass-and-afterclass-behavior-in-case-of-multiple-test-cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485457/junit-beforeclass-and-afterclass-behavior-in-case-of-multiple-test-cases)

Comment: AfterClass runs after class. It does not run after "some" non test methods.

Comment: @kamaci "Some" non-test methods? Just call the method, or organize your tests differently, or use AOP.

Comment: I just try to find a way to do this withing JUnit. Something like: "if a methods is called run another method." I do not use a AOP framework within my project.

Comment: @kamaci "If a method is called run another method" is called "calling the method where you need to". There's no way to identify arbitrary methods and call them at arbitrary times, other than simply calling them when you need to, in Java or jUnit. That's not jUnit's purpose, either.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call those methods manually or through AOP if you are using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TestWatcher to listen to when the test has finished, & check the test-name to see if your code should be ran. E.g.:

```
@Rule
public TestRule runFooSomtimes = new TestWatcher() {

    public void foo() {
      //do stuff here
    }

    List<String> methodsToCheck = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("testMethodOne");
    }}

    @Override
    protected void finished(Description description) {
        if(methodsToCheck.contains(description.getMethodName())) {
            foo();
        }
    }
};
```

(Excuse any errors, away from an IDE at the moment, but should give an idea.)