# Do something before and after tests

Tags: testing, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I have several Junit/Selenium WebDriver tests, each one in separate class. Still I have not been able to implement methods which should be run before and after ALL tests are run. Not before or after class, because then they run before and after every test.

I must implement some sort of test suite, but how that is done e.g without adding all the classes manually to suite?

Comment: How is it that you are running these tests? Is it command line, IDE or some build tool like Maven or Ant?

Comment: One method is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007425/how-to-load-dbunit-test-data-once-per-case-with-spring-test/9006655#9006655

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921515/junit-4-beforeclass-afterclass-when-using-suites). It is about having a method that executes before a test suite runs.

You need to have a static method annotated with `BeforeClass` in your test suite. Your test suite references all test classes, but have a look at the example in the QA and you will see it's not that tedious when you use the `Suite` runner with thes `@SuiteClasses` annotation.

I don't know any built-in method you could use to add the test cases to the suite otherwise than manually.

Comment: How about adding the tests to suite with package names or file extensions?

Comment: As I wrote above, I'm not aware of any built-in solution to your problem. So I would extend the `Suite` runner (code [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/junit/runners/Suite.java.html)), defining a custom annotation representing the packages where your tests live. Then at initialization time, use the [reflexions library](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) to discover the test classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if JUnit is able to do the things you want. You might want to try TestNG. You don't need to change your Test but you can do stuff like @BeforeSuite to run a method before every test you got in that suite. [Klick here](http://testng.org/doc/index.html)